# Why pagination does not work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Here's how the document looks in the collection:

```js
const request = {
            carNum: carNum,
            userId: userId,
            comm: comm,
            location: location,
            data: new Date(),
            status: 'wait',
            geo: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
        };
```

When I try to change start point for a query (startAfter). Firebase sends me the same value every time. Why?

```js
let docRef = db.collection('requests').orderBy('data').startAfter(3).limit(3);
        try {
            let doc = await docRef.get()
            console.log(doc);
            console.log('Hello');
        } catch (e) {
            result = e;
        }
```

Comment: Note that `starAfter()` parameter shall be of similar type of the data you find at this node. In other words, `startAfter(3)` will not start after the 3rd item in your collection but after the first document for which data = '3'

Comment: And how to sort by date?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `starAfter()` parameter shall be of similar type than the data you find at this node.

In other words, a query with `startAfter(3)` will not start after the 3rd item in your collection but after the first document for which data = 3.

You could store your data as a Timestamp:

```
const request = {
            carNum: carNum,
            userId: userId,
            comm: comm,
            location: location,
            data: new Date().getTime(),   // <- get the Timestamp
            status: 'wait',
            geo: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude),
        };
```

and query it with a Timestamp:

```
let docRef = db.collection('requests').orderBy('data').startAfter(1528074000).limit(3)
```

However, take care that the above is not a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) but a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference). You will have to loop over the results you received in order to get the documents.